# How to configure sqlite to display headers by default

Tags: sqlite, header, config

Is there any way to configure sqlite3 so that the headers will display by default?

I know I can use `.headers on` to turn on headers, but I have to keep typing it every time I launch the client because the setting doesn't stick between sessions.  I want the headers to be on permanently.

Comment: For anyone using Windows, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147547/change-sqlite-default-settings-in-windows) provided a bit more clarity.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/sqlite3.1.html):

> **INIT FILE**
>   sqlite3 reads an initialization file to set the configuration of the interactive environment.
>   [...]
>   If the file `~/.sqliterc` exists, it is processed first.  can be found in the user's home directory, it is read and processed.  It should generally only contain meta-commands.

So just put a file called `.sqliterc` in your home directory and put this in it:

```
.headers ON
```

Comment: Be careful with the content of the ~/sqliterc file, comments are not allowed (lines begining with #), could stop interpretation of the config file.

Comment: I found adding `.mode columns` as well to .sqliterc made the results much easier to read. This will align the headers with the values.

Comment: Full list of "dot commands" can be found here: https://sqlite.org/cli.html#special_commands_to_sqlite3_dot_commands_.

Comment: I've been using SQLite for over a decade, never knew this existed. Thank you!

Answer (score 35):

You can pass arguments in the command line too:

```
sqlite3 db.db  -header -column  "select x from y;"
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for what other `-switches` can be passed?