# Change SQLite default settings in Windows

Tags: sqlite, header, output

I have created a file in my home directory in Windows and have written inside:

.mode column
.header on
.nullvalue NULL
.separator

To change de default output but when I try to execute: select * from table;  it stills has the default settings with headers off, etc.

Does someone have some idea of what happens?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory that `sqlite3` assumes to be the home directoy is specified in the environment variables `USERPROFILE`, `HOME`, or `HOMEDRIVE`+`HOMEPATH`.
Check that at least one of these is set correctly.

The file must have the exact name `.sqliterc`.
Explorer does not allow to create file names beginning with a period; you might have to rename it in the console.