# How to get a list of column names with Sqlite.swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

For debugging purposes I am trying to get a simple list of the column names in my SQLite table. I am using the [SQLite.swift framework](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift).

My question is more specific than [How to get a list of column names on sqlite3 / iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947215/how-to-get-a-list-of-column-names-on-sqlite3-iphone) so I am creating a new question.

Using

```
try db.execute("PRAGMA table_info(table_name);")
```

by applying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/948204/3681880) to the [documentation](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#executing-arbitrary-sql) didn't work for me (nothing happened).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you already have a database connection called `db` set up, to get a list of the column names, you can use the following code:

```
do {

    let tableInfo = Array(try db.prepare("PRAGMA table_info(table_name)"))
    for line in tableInfo {
        print(line[1]!, terminator: " ")
    }
    print()

} catch _ { }
```

where `table_name` is replaced with the literal string of your table's name.

You can also add

```
print(tableInfo)
```

to see more pragma info about your table.

**Credits**

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29866725/3681880) for clues of how to do this.

**Example Function**

Tested routine from [Joe Blow](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36784597/2) to save a little typing:

```
func findColumns(_ tableName:String) {

    var asAnArray:[String] = []
    do {
        let s = try db!.prepare("PRAGMA table_info(" + tableName + ")" )
        for row in s { asAnArray.append(row[1]! as! String) }
    }
    catch { print("some woe in findColumns for \(tableName) \(error)") }

    let asAString = asAnArray.joined(separator: ",")

    print(asAnArray)
    print(asAString)
}
```