# sqlite: How to use SELECT COUNT in CASE statement?

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to **add a column if the column doesn't exist already** using SQLite. After looking at a ton of stack overflow questions, I believe the only way to do this in an SQL statement is to use [`pragma_table_info`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46319021/1696153) (however this is only available for sqlite v3.16 and further).

So, I'm trying to **run the `ALTER` query if the `SELECT COUNT` query is `> 0`.**

Here's my attempts, all are throwing **syntax error**.

Try #1

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNTREC 
   CASE CNTREC 
      WHEN CNTREC > 0 
      THEN
         ALTER TABLE runs ADD scheduledRun BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
      END
FROM pragma_table_info('runs') 
WHERE name='scheduledRun';
```

Try #2

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNTREC 
   CASE  
      WHEN CNTREC > 0 
      THEN
         ALTER TABLE runs ADD scheduledRun BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
      END
FROM pragma_table_info('runs') 
WHERE name='scheduledRun';
```

Try #3

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNTREC FROM pragma_table_info('runs') WHERE name='scheduledRun';
CASE CNTREC WHEN CNTREC > 0 
THEN
    ALTER TABLE runs ADD scheduledRun BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
END
```

Try #4

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNTREC FROM pragma_table_info('runs') WHERE name='scheduledRun'
CASE CNTREC WHEN CNTREC > 0 
THEN
    ALTER TABLE runs ADD scheduledRun BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
END
```

Try #5

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNTREC FROM pragma_table_info('runs') WHERE name='scheduledRun'
CASE WHEN CNTREC > 0 
THEN
    ALTER TABLE runs ADD scheduledRun BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
END
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Docs: [Case](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html), [Select](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html), [Alter](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

Please do not give me any Java or C++ code, I'm looking for a **pure sqlite** solution only.

Comment: I am not sure you will be able to do it in pure SQL Script. If SQLite supports [`ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-altertable.html) it would be easy. You need begin/end block and IF statement to conditionally run code. Case expression works on query level(it is only text) that is not executed.

Comment: bummer :( I was worried it wasn't possible. I've tried `ALTER TABLE results ADD api_description IF NOT EXISTS TEXT  DEFAULT ''` but still get an error `Error: duplicate column name: api_description` @LukaszSzozda

Comment: [Conditionally add columns in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891563/conditionally-add-columns-in-sqlite)

Comment: You will need a external script to run 1) query to check metadata 2) conditionally execute DDL statement. If only SQLite supports dynamic SQL :/

Comment: Thank you @LukaszSzozda, yeah I think it's not possible to do it in pure sqlite T_T

Comment: Please leave the question open, I would really like to be wrong or read about some clever workaround :)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda hah that is true! Hopefully one day someone will have the answer :)