# Print column names in SQLite3 output along with query results

Tags: android, sqlite

When I do this in Android:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM secure WHERE name='mock_location' OR value=2.2 ORDER BY value ASC;
```

I get this:

```
44|mock_location|1
56|facelock_liveliness_recognition_threshold|2.2
```

But I want the column names for (*) in the first row, like this:

```
_id|name|value
44|mock_location|1
56|facelock_liveliness_recognition_threshold|2.2
```

How can I do that in a single query?

Comment: If you are use it with Cursor . You can get it by java code

Comment: I can't use Cursor because I am trying to construct the cursor.

Comment: Are you using CursorFactory ?

Comment: I am extending AbstractCursor.

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Comment: When query is executed from within the ContentProvider, I issue a CLI call that returns the result above. However I need to construct a cursor to return, and it needs to not only point to the results but also to the column names. However, I don't want to issue another query just for that, so I figure I could parse the column names directly from the result if I could get them from there.

Comment: if you are launching `sqlite3` tool so it means you are getting the data from your local filesytem, so why dont you simply do that using `SQLiteDatabase` ?

Comment: Because I need superuser permission, and as far as I know, I can only do that via command line, right?

Comment: try `.headers on`

Comment: Can I issue in one-shot command line call?

Comment: never tried, but i think that should work, just separate them with `\n` (or `\r\n`)

Comment: Related [How to get a list of column names on Sqlite3 database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/947215/3744182), specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48756911/3744182) by Sam Houston.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this and it works:

```
sqlite3 -header /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "SELECT * FROM secure WHERE name='mock_location' OR value=2.2 ORDER BY value ASC;"
```