# Why does SQLite create empty sqlite_sequence table?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sequence, auto-increment

I have a database of several tables in which the first field is defined as:

```
'ID' INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE ... PRIMARY_KEY('ID')
```

I do not use the AUTOINCREMENT keyword for any of these tables yet my db contains an empty sqlite_sequence table which I cannot delete. Inserting records into these tables with a NULL value for the ID field generates default incremental values for the ID fields but does not populate or update the sqlite_sequence table. Is there any way I can reset the last inserted rowid value to 0 for these tables?

Comment: When you define an integer column as PRIMARY_KEY it is also AUTOINCREMENT. Read more here: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: `UNIQUE` on a primary key column is redundant and pointless, btw.

Comment: Did you have a table with an `AUTOINCREMENT` integer PK at some point and then drop it?

Comment: @Shawn, regarding UNIQUE, point taken. Regarding previously existing but now dropped table, I can't recall but if no longer "active" and empty why can't I delete it?

Comment: It's an internal table (as are all that start with `sqlite_` and explicitly cannot be dropped once the system creates it. https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#the_sqlite_sequence_table

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase my original question: 
How do I reset the last inserted rowid to 0 for a table in a db where sqite_sequence is absent or empty and not used?

Comment: i believe a simple `UPDATE` command could do it but resetting/altering a sequence is most of the time a bad idea..

Comment: In a rowid table without `AUTOINCREMENT`, a new rowid is calculated based on the current maximum rowid present in the table. See the link that forpas provided for a complete description of the algorithm. tl;dr: reset it by deleting all rows from the table.

Answer (score 0):

According to your SQL below, I think you created `sqlite_autoindex_...` table with [UNIQUE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#unique_constraints) instead of [sqlite_sequence](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab) table with [AUTOINCREMENT](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html). *`sqlite_sequence` table is never ever created unless you create a table with an `AUTOINCREMENT` column.:

> ID' INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE ... PRIMARY_KEY('ID')

[The doc](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#automatic_indexes) says below:

> Do not confuse automatic indexes with the internal indexes (having names like "sqlite_autoindex_table_N") that are sometimes created to implement a PRIMARY KEY constraint or UNIQUE constraint.

For example, you create `test` table which has `id` column with `TEXT PRIMARY KEY` or `TEXT UNIQUE` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  id TEXT UNIQUE
);
```

Then, `sqlite_autoindex_test_1` table is created as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947215/how-to-get-a-list-of-column-names-on-sqlite3-database#72267268) explains how to show column names:

```
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode box
sqlite> SELECT name FROM sqlite_master;
┌───────┬─────────────────────────┐
│ type  │          name           │
├───────┼─────────────────────────┤
│ table │ test                    │
│ index │ sqlite_autoindex_test_1 │
└───────┴─────────────────────────┘
```

In addition, you create `test` table which has `id` column with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Then, `sqlite_autoindex_test_1` table is not created as shown below.

```
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode box
sqlite> SELECT type, name FROM sqlite_master; 
┌───────┬──────┐
│ type  │ name │
├───────┼──────┤
│ table │ test │
└───────┴──────┘
```

But, you create `test` table which has `id` column with `INTEGER UNIQUE` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INTEGER UNIQUE
);
```

Then, `sqlite_autoindex_test_1` table is created as shown below:

```
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode box
sqlite> SELECT name FROM sqlite_master;
┌───────┬─────────────────────────┐
│ type  │          name           │
├───────┼─────────────────────────┤
│ table │ test                    │
│ index │ sqlite_autoindex_test_1 │
└───────┴─────────────────────────┘
```