# Most efficient way to store large amount of API data in an sqlite3 database using python

Tags: python, json, api, sqlite

I am accessing an HTTP REST API using `requests`. The API returns JSON which I would like to parse and then commit to an sqlite3 database. One JSON response might look roughly like the following:

```
{
    entry1: 
        {
            key1:value1, 
            key2:value2
        }, 
    entry2:
        {
            key2:value2
        }
}
```

Another may look like the following:

```
{
    entry3: 
        {
            key1:value1, 
            key2:value2,
            key3:value3
        }, 
}
```

I would like to save this to a table as follows:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| entry  | key1   | key2   | key3   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| entry1 | value1 | value2 | NULL   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| entry2 | NULL   | value2 | NULL   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| entry3 | value1 | value2 | value3 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

In reality I am looping over around thousands of entries. My issue is as follows:

**I do not know all the possible keys `key1`, `key2`, `key3` ... `key_n` that can occur, as the API does not document this. It is also too costly for me to do one loop over the entire dataset just to figure out which columns could *possibly* occur as every request to the API is charged.**

There is one obvious solution, namely to check whether the columns to all entries for the current request exist in my table, and adding columns to the table as needed.

My question is twofold:

- Should I perform the above check the above in my python code in a `pandas.DataFrame` OR should I commit directly to my `sqlite3` database using SQL commands, thereby bypassing the need to store the `DataFrame` in my RAM during runtime? Is it bad practice to add columns like this (i.e using an `ALTER TABLE` statement) in `sqlite3`?
- Have I overlooked other (potentially better) ways to go about this?

Comment: Have you looked at the "JSON1" extension https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html

Comment: @JonSG thanks, but python is much more versatile when it comes to working with and manipulating JSON

Answer (score 0):

SQlite3 does not allow the *full* alteration of tables. It allows tables to be renamed, and columns to be added and dropped (which is what it sounds like you need) but that is all. [More info on that here.](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

However, with what you're importing it sounds like you need a non-relational database. Have you considered using something like [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/)? It would allow you to throw any object into the database and call it back based on what data you need.

Assuming that's not an option, I believe your best bet would be to use python to [query your SQlite3 table info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/948204/12425097) and use the result from there to add a column if required either per-item (which would be costly) or for all items at once. You could do so for all items at once by sending one large cover-all query to your API, and then storing the return in a txt file which you then parse to adapt the table and store the data.

Comment: Adding columns is all I will be needing, so that should be enough. MongoDB sounds cool but I think it would be an overkill for this particular project. There is no large cover-all query. This is a commercial API and it is designed in such a way as to require that users make requests based on precisely what data (which "entry") they need...

Comment: Then as written, a request followed by a column creation if required, is your best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Just store your API information in a temporary table `features` with three columns `id`, `ftype` and `feature`. After scrolling, create the final table `representations` based on `SELECT DISTINCT ftype FROM features` and do something like

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO representations(id,?) VALUES(?,?)",((ftype,ID,feat,) for ID,ftype,field in rows));
```

while scrolling `features` with another cursor to get `rows`.

WARNING: I did not test this.

As suggested by @LaytonGB you can also use a text file for this.