# I need to format a column value in my return but that column may not exist in which case I need to grab the rest of the columns data

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an app that uses a local sqlite database which has a particular table called 'Theme' for each project. Sometimes that table has a column 'startDate' and sometimes it does not. I need to have that 'startDate' returned in a particular format if it does exist. My problem is, when I query this table, specifying the neccessary format, if the column does not exist, the query returns an error "NO SUCH COLUMN".

HOW DO I CHECK FOR COLUMN EXISTENCE, IF IT DOES EXIST, RETURN THE 'startDate' PROPERLY FORMATTED ALONG WITH THE REST OF THE DATA, IF IT DOES NOT EXIST, RETURN THE REST OF THE DATA WITHOUT THE 'startDate'???

This must be done in 1 query!

Something like this...

```
SELECT *  (if exists STRFTIME('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S', startDate) AS sDate FROM Theme
```

Comment: How come your app does not know the structure of its DB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a list of column names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685206/how-to-get-a-list-of-column-names)

Comment: You could use a `select *` and check the columns in the result, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14004784/1015327

Comment: Or try [`PRAGMA table_info(table_name)`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info).

Comment: @Hanno Because, as the DB is now, some projects have date info in their 'Theme' table while some do NOT have date info in their 'Theme' table

Comment: @Klas 'How to get a list of column names' suggests querying the DB for a list of column names and then using that data. I can only make one query

Comment: In that case I'd also be interested in the answer. Does a failed query count as a query? If that's ok, then assume the column exists, and if that fails run the query without the date field.

Answer (score 0):

Only one query:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  do {
    for(String columnName : cursor.getColumnNames()) {
      // do something
    }
  } while(cursor.moveToNext());
} else {
  // your actions for empty table
}
cursor.close();
```